# Generalised Spherical Bessel Equation

Tags: special-functions

can anyone give me a reference about the following kind of generalised spherical Bessel equation:

$$\left[x^2\partial_x^2  +2x\partial_x +k^2(x^2+\alpha x)-l(l+1)\right]f(x)=0$$

or for $u(x)=xf(x)$:

$$\left[\partial_x^2+k^2\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{x}\right)-\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}\right]u(x)=0.$$

I could not find any "modified" or "generalised" form of Bessel's equation that included a linear term like the $k^2\alpha x$ term above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $\rho=kx$ and $u(x)=w(\rho)$, this equation becomes the [Coulomb wave equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/33.2.E1):
$$\frac{{\mathrm{d}}^{2}w}{{\mathrm{d}\rho}^{2}}+\left(1+\frac{ak}{\rho}-%
\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{\rho^{2}}\right)w=0$$
Solutions of the initial equation are then 
$$ f(x)=\frac{A}{x}F_\ell\left(-\frac{ak}2,kx\right)+\frac{B}{x}F_\ell\left(-\frac{ak}2,kx\right)$$
build from the Coulomb functions.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have found this out as well in the meantime.